# Error detaching Instances from Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

In trying to detach a list of more than 50 instances from EC2 autoscaling, I got the following validation error :

```
 conn_as.detach_instances(autoScalingGroup.name,listOfInstances,decrement_capacity=True)
```

> List exceeds the maximum number of instances to detach. Please retry
>   your request with fewer instances.

How can I force the detachment of all the requested number of instances ?

Note: I am using boto2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Official documentation [AWS AutoScaling Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-account-limits.html),

> You can use AttachInstances, DetachInstances, EnterStandby, and ExitStandby with at most 20 instance IDs at a time.

So, either you can reduce the number at your end or raise a support ticket with AWS to check if they can increase the limit for your account.